# C++ STL reverse string search, down to a bounding index

Tags: c++, string, search, stl, c++20

Consider

```
std::string reasonStr
```

and a call

```
reasonStr.find(").", sepIndex)
```

which finds the first occurrence of `")."` in `reasonStr`, but earliest at `sepIndex`.
I want to find the *last* such occurence, earliest at `sepIndex`.
But a call

```
reasonStr.rfind(").", sepIndex)
```

instead [seems to](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/) start its right-to-left search at `sepIndex`, down to 0. Furthermore,

```
string::size_type s = reasonStr.rfind(").");
s = s < sepIndex ? string::npos : s;
```

obtains the desired result, but can search way too far (i.e. below `sepIndex`). Alternatively, I could search inside of `reasonStr.substr(sepIndex)`, but that seems like an unnecessary copy.

In conclusion, these functions have parameters where to start their search, but not where to end it. I would like to use such STL functions on strings which tell where to end the search.

More precisely, I would like to use STL to find a substring in reverse order, and specify a lower index bound from which on it can possibly occur, *without* first taking a substring of the string to search.

Are there any such functions in the C++20 STL?

I even looked for it in the Boost library and could not find it. Pointing to Boost would also be helpful, in case the standard does not provide it.

**Edit / Solution**

I accepted the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64224643/3410351) that shows how to use `std::string_view` to do just that. I went with:

```
string::size_type s = string_view(reasonStr.begin() + sepIndex, reasonStr.end()).rfind(").");
if (s != string_view::npos)
    s += sepIndex;
```

Comment: Have you considered `string::find_last_of`?

Comment: Yes, but that does not find a full string, but [any](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) characters that occur in the string, right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Something like construct proper `std::string_view` and then `rfind`?

Comment: You can consider finding the first character and check the next, anyway, `boost::algorithm::find_last` can be an option if you can use it.

Comment: @fas Can I construct a `std::string_view` to represent a `std::string` substring without allocations?

Comment: @anastaciu I looked at `boost::algorithm::find_last` and it doesn't seem to have that option either.

Comment: @xamid, it returns an iterator to the beginning of the last substring, is that not usable for you?

Comment: @anastaciu The point is to not do unnecessary search or allocation.

Comment: @fas Your suggestion was correct, unfortunately now someone else gave an answer before you, how to use it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the last occurence starting earlist at `sepIndex`, you can create a `std::string_view` and search that in reverse. It doesn't allocate (copy) anything, it just points to the original data. This is an important note as you must ensure that the `string_view` refers to an existing object - if the `string_view` outlives the `string` it points to, using the `string_view` is undefined behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "This ) is a string ). with ). three matches";
    std::size_t sepIndex = 18;
    std::string pattern = ").";
    std::string_view sv(s.begin() + sepIndex, s.end());

    auto pos = sv.rfind(pattern);
    if (pos != std::string_view::npos) {
        std::cout << sepIndex + pos << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No match found\n";
    }
}
```